# What am I missing in this SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've written some SQL for a MySQL database.

```
SELECT U.Id, U.Name, U.Surname 
  FROM match M 
 INNER JOIN created_by C 
    ON C.MatchId = M.Id 
 INNER JOIN user U 
    ON U.Id = C.UserId 
 WHERE M.Id = 3
```

I'm going crazy because it doesn't seem wrong but the interpreter says there is a syntax error here near `'match M INNER JOIN created_by C ON C.MatchId=M.Id INNER JOIN user U O'`.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`MATCH` is a [MySQL reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).  Enclose it in backticks if you intend to use it as a column or table name.

```
SELECT U.Id, U.Name, U.Surname 
  FROM `match` M
```

Answer (score 3):

I think <strike>`user` &</strike> `match` is an reserved keyword. You need to escape it. Try the following query

```
SELECT U.Id, U.Name, U.Surname 
  FROM `match` M 
 INNER JOIN `created_by` C 
    ON C.MatchId = M.Id 
 INNER JOIN `user` U 
    ON U.Id = C.UserId 
 WHERE M.Id = 3
```